# Why can't I successfully use 'call' on Array.isArray?

Tags: javascript

So I'm used to automatically writing things such as this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

--and similar such applications of various methods via `Array.prototype.XXX.call` or `Object.prototype.XXX.call([])`.

So I went to try out the `Array.isArray` method which I didn't know existed, and automatically wrote `Array.prototype.isArray.call`, which of course failed since `isArray` isn't defined on the prototype.

But then I tried `Array.isArray.call([])` slightly unthinkingly and got `false`, which confused me.

It worked fine on the third try when I went the plain ol' boring way (the correct usage) and simply wrote `Array.isArray(thing_to_be_tested)`, but why did I get `false` on the previous attempt? I don't understand why that doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you "automatically" write stuff like that ?

Comment: Because you were basically calling `Array.isArray()` (only in a `[]` context), and without arguments it tells you that `undefined` is not an array.

Comment: @Adeneo When you're in the middle of working with the native APIs and playing with them and bending what they can do....

Comment: Well, `isArray` is not part of the prototype chain, and it only accepts one argument, and doesn't care about the `this` value or scope, so don't !

Comment: And you should generally avoid converting arguments, nodelist etc. to array that way as well, even if it is useful sometimes, and I must confess to do doing it quite a bit myself, even knowing the proper way is to use a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing `.call()` expects is the *context*. So you're basically calling `.isArray()` with the context of an Array, but an `undefined` value.

Call instead:

```
Array.isArray.call( null, [] );
```

<strike>or to make it more realistic:</strike>

```
var isarr = Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.isArray, null );
```

Now you can call that like

```
isarr( [] );
```

Comment: or to make it more simple: `var isArr = Array.isArray;`

Comment: If at all, use `var isArr = Array.isArray.bind(Array);`.

Comment: haha yes indeed. For that method the context has no meaning and it should just be referenced directly.

Comment: Ah I though with ES6 and subclassable arrays that might change, but [apparently it doesn't](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.isarray).

Comment: Still, the method is not on the prototype chain. So contrary to for instance `Object.prototype.toString` we can just reference the method in a variable whilst that would not work for the `toString` example.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Array.isArray` has one argument, which you are not passing along. You are simply passing the `this` value, which is not used in the function:

```
Array.isArray.call(null, [])
```

Comment: I knew that. Really I swear I did. Not enough coffee. 12 minutes til I can accept answer, lol.